# How to fix Prestashop product sorting (1.6.1.3)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

As the title suggest, I am having issues trying to reorder products in the category which translate onto the front end.

When sorting the products I get a green prompt that it has successfully updated, however on a refresh it reverts back to how it was displayed before.

Therefore all of my products are orangised in the order they were listed which is a problem as I require them in a specific order which is not possible at this time.

Has anyone else had a similar issue and possibly have a solution.

TIA.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far to solve this problem and how it failed.

Comment: I am a front end developer for my company and have no real experience with any backend programming for prestashop so I cannot look into the actual 'workings' of it.

However, I have tried looking for solutions with no real answers, but as far as trying I have only tried on multiple browsers and devices and still get the same effect.

We have used prestashop previously (just a few versions older) and never had this problem. It only seems to be on this version (which now due to the template we cannot update).

Comment: After reorder product try click on bar with url link and press ENTER, page will reload and it supposed to do the job.

Comment: From which tab you are changing order of products ?

Comment: Agnes Tom, I will give it a try and hopefully this works. Sorry Nimish, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, could you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have installed the blocklayered module? Try turning off "Show products in subcategories" (translated from my spanish version PS).
It solved my problem!

Comment: For the moment simplest solution but I cannot find out why this is working.

Answer (score 1):

Is not the best solution but This just worked for me:

1. Drag the desired category to the desired position
2. Wait until the Success message "disappear" by itself
3. Place your cursor on the address navigation bar on your navigator and press enter in order to reload the page
4. Voila! the position is saved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be related to the caching of the product list page in the backoffice. I don't have a code solution to fix the problem - Prestashop was made aware of this problem more than 3 years ago, but still does not work in the most recent versions of Chrome OR Firefox.

So here is a procedural "workaround"...

1) Drag your item to its intended location in the list, wait for the green success popup to disappear, click on any category in the "Filter by Category" area.

2) Once the page refreshes, click back on the category you are working in and the change should have stayed.

2a) You may need to do step 2 one or two times to get this sync'd correctly.

3) Once you get an item to stick to the position you want, you need to repeat steps 1 and 2 above for each "item position" change you make.

This is the ONLY way I can change the sort order of products within a category in the Backoffice with any of the two browsers mentioned (from several version back I might add).

Hope this helps... with the more recent release of Prestashop 1.7, I hope this problem goes away and I don't have to dig through the code to find a fix.

PS: DO NOT attempt to upgrade a 1.6 store to 1.7 unless you KNOW what you are doing - lots of stuff gets broken in that process!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it is greatly appreciated. Prestashop support is infuriating and it's like they don't want to fix issues.

I will give this a try and hope fully it will work. But to give you a heads up, it is the same in 1.7, we use a 1.7 install for another shop and it is plagued with many of the same bugs and issues as 1.6 but at least most of them are fixable even if it means digging around in code.

Again, thank you for the feedback.